# CentOS 6.8 - Installing Python 2.7 leads to a circular dependency error impossible to fix

Tags: python-2.7, centos, centos6

I have a fresh new minimal installation of CentOS 6.8 where I'm trying to have Python 2.7 with its tools.

First, I started with:

```
yum -y update
yum groupinstall -y development
yum install -y zlib-dev openssl-devel sqlite-devel bzip2-devel
```

Then I downloaded the Python 2.7.13 package and installed it normally with:

```
./configure
make
make altinstall
```

But then, when trying to install setuptools with:

```
wget http://url.to.setup.tools.package
tar xf file
cd folder
python2.7 setup.py install
```

it says that the **six** package is missing.
If I want to install the **six** package, it says that the **packaging** package is missing. If I want to install the **packaging** package, it says that the **pyparsing** package is missing. If I want to install the **pyparsing** package, it says that the **setuptools** package is missing.

How can this happen? Is now Python 2.7.13 installing itself without anything?
Is there any other way to install Python 2.7 separately from the original Python 2.6 that CentOS 6.8 has?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could manually install **EPEL** repo and then **IUS** repo:

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uhv epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
wget https://centos6.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
rpm -Uhv ius-release.rpm
```

Then you can install Python-2.7 like this:

```
yum -y install python27 python27-devel python27-pip python27-setuptools python27-virtualenv --enablerepo=ius
```

Then whatever python script you might have that you want to use Python 2.7.x instead of 2.6 (which is default installed on CentOS 6.x) you have to edit that script and do a simple replace (replace python with python2.7) and you're good to go!

Comment: Yes, you are right. Finally the IUS repo saved everything. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad that it worked and that I was able to help!